About Pillai's conjecture
I have been reading about this conjecture... Some posts in here and some other on the internet. In Wikipedia, I found an interesting table that shows for each $k \in \mathbb{N}$, which $x, y, n, m \in \mathbb{N}$ satisfy that:

$x^n - y^m = k$,  for that fixed $k$.

You can find this table here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture#Pillai%27s_conjecture

When watching this table, you can see that for $k \in \{6, 14, 34, 42, 50, 58, 62\}$,

$\{(x,y,n,m)\in \mathbb{N} : x^n - y^m = k\} = \emptyset $

I have some questions about these numbers:

Every odd $k$ has at least one solution? (Why are all these $k$ even?)
How could I prove that for a specific $k \in \mathbb{N}$, for instance, $k=6$, there are no solutions? Is there a consistent method to solve this problems?

I'm just a student and probably have not much background to approach this questions correctly. Any help will be well received.

Welcome to MSE! Your question is a good one, and I hope you get a satisfactory answer :)

The way it is written, the presumptive requirement that $m\ge 2, n\ge 2$ is not present and the statement of the set equality is false.

Thank you Brevan!
Abiessu, you are right. Also they can't be both equal to 2. But I think the question is clear anyway.

To answer 2. This is a wide open conjecture. Only the case $k=1$ is fully solved , for other $k$'s only search limits are established (no idea how high). So we do not know whether the solution set is actually empty for the presented cases. However , chances are high that this is the case. The empty cases must have the form $4k+2$ since a positive integer not having this form is the difference of two squares.
